# Vuetify v-carousel arrows overlapping problem

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuetify.js

I met a problem with Vuetify v-carousel. Where the left and right arrows are overlapping on the left side. 
**Image**
[image]

**Vue file**

```
<template>
  <v-card v-if="propertyThis">
    <v-carousel
      cycle
      hide-delimiters
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(item,i) in propertyThis.pictures"
        :key="i"
        :src="item"
      />
    </v-carousel>
```

**package.json file**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2"
  },
```

I didn't see an obvious difference to the codes on [this page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#hide-delimiters). 
How to fix it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Update:

I commented out all lines in the .css files and in between the 'style' tag in the .vue files. But the problem is still there.
Here is the html parts from the page:

```
<div class="v-window__prev">
    <button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--dark v-size--default" aria-label="Previous visual">
        <span class="v-btn__content">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-left theme--dark" style="font-size: 36px;"/>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="v-window__next">
    <button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--dark v-size--default" aria-label="Next visual">
        <span class="v-btn__content">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-right theme--dark" style="font-size: 36px;"/>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I cannot find anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Do you have any custom css?

Comment: I would advice to inspect the element via your browsers dev-tools to see if your css might overwrite the components.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I solved the problem by adding a v-app tag before the v-card tag.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      ...
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Hope it helps someone with a similar problem.